# power series where $f(z)=e^z$ and $z_0=1$

Tags: power-series

How do i find the power series of the form:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n ({z-z_0)}$$

where $f(z)=e^z$ and $z_0=1$

using the geomatric series currently i have that it equals

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ({e^z-1)}$$

However i dont believe this is correct since it in terms of $e^z$ rather than $z$

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a standard formula for a power series centered at a point $a$: $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f^{(n)}(a) (z-a)^{n}/n!$. Is there any particular reason why this has been tagged with complex analysis?

Comment: By $f(x)$, do you mean $z$? Because $f$ isn't in your summand. And neither is $x$, for that matter.

Answer (score 2):

you can just use :
$$ e^z=e\cdot e^{z-1}$$ and then compute the series expansion on $0$ and you obtain:
$$e^z=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}e\cdot\frac{(z-1)^n}{n!} $$